# Modelling non-structured tabular data in a database

Tags: excel, xml, database-design, spreadsheet

I have data that is in the following format:

[image]

The grid can be up to a million rows and about 10k columns. Furthermore, there may be thousands of documents like this. I think the best way to model this data is using the Excel-like approach, which, using XML, comes out to something like the following:

```
<sheetData>
    <row r="1" spans="1:4" x14ac:dyDescent="0.2">
        <c r="A1" s="1" t="s">
            <v>0</v> <!-- Means Value of type String (t="s") at 
                          A1 with value found at index 0 in 
                          a sharedStrings reference document -->
        </c>
        <c r="B1" s="1"/>  <!-- Means no data at cell B1 -->
        <c r="C1" s="1"/>  <!-- Means no data at cell C1 -->
        <c r="D1" s="1"/>  <!-- Means no data at cell D1 -->
    </row>
    <row r="2" spans="1:4" x14ac:dyDescent="0.2">
        <c r="A2" s="1"/>
        <c r="B2" s="1" t="s">
            <v>1</v>
        </c>
        <c r="C2" s="1"/>
        <c r="D2" s="1"/>
    </row>
    <row r="3" spans="1:4" x14ac:dyDescent="0.2">
        <c r="A3" s="1"/>
        <c r="B3" s="1"/>
        <c r="C3" s="1" t="s">
            <v>2</v>
        </c>
        <c r="D3" s="1"/>
    </row>
    <row r="4" spans="1:4" x14ac:dyDescent="0.2">
        <c r="A4" s="1"/>
        <c r="B4" s="1"/>
        <c r="C4" s="1"/>
        <c r="D4" s="1" t="s">
            <v>3</v>
        </c>
    </row>
</sheetData>
```

The value in the Excel xml is a reference to a sharedStrings file, so something like `<v>1</v>` could reference a string "Data".

The most common operations I need to allow on this data are:

- Editing a cell
- Moving/inserting/deleting a column
- Moving/inserting/deleting a row

I'm familiar with the EAV data model for spreadsheets, but for the above, non-structured data, I'm not sure the best approach for this. I suppose MongoDB might be the "most similar" to an xml-store, in that it's a json-store, but what might be a good way to save this data?

Another possibility I was thinking was storing it in a relational database such as:

```
- spreadsheet_id
- row
- col
- value
```

However, this becomes almost impossible when considering the editing of the document, if we're allowing operations such as "Insert a new row at position 0", which would literally require updating every single value (there could be a billion) for that spreadsheet, just to insert a single row.

What might be a good way to store this? If anyone knows, how does Google Sheets store their data?

Comment: Have you considered using an XML database?

Comment: There is no big difference between document-oriented (XML) and EAV models if you need to re-enumerate rows after inserting/deleting isn't it?

Comment: @serge well I was thinking if it was stored in an array-like object, you could just insert/delete at that index. And for columns, well then it looks like we're back to square one where we have to update everything (unless there's another way?)

Comment: @MichaelKay thanks for the suggestion -- a couple questions from that: (1) what would be an example xml database to use (I've never used one); and (2) what would be the difference between using an xml database and a json one (mongo, for example)?

Comment: (1) the top three are probably exist-DB, BaseX, and MarkLogic; (b) you've shown us XML data rather than JSON data so for a start, the data wouldn't need any conversion. Plus, there are standards for XML query languages, but there are no real standards for a JSON query language.